# how to save an array of strings into a text file using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to search for  strings in a text file 'marine_forservers.txt' according to the indices saved in 'x.txt' and then save those strings in output file
This is the code I tried but it can't save strings to files
Can anyone help me??

```
search = importdata('marine_forservers.txt');
patterns=importdata('x.txt');
fid = fopen('outputI.txt','w');
for i=1:length(patterns)
    for j = 1:16709
        if(j==patterns(i))
         str= search(j);
         fprintf(fid, '%s\n', str);
   end
end
end
fclose(fid);
```

I got this Error in ==> suppI at 8
             fprintf(fid, '%s\n', str);

Comment: Your code for writing a string to a text file looks okay. I would guess that for some iteration in your double loop `str` is not a string. Can you provide an example (in the question) of what `search` and `patterns` look like? Perhaps we can eliminate that double loop and fix your problem in one hit... ps I don't know who down-voted this but it is not obvious to me why it received a downvote?

Comment: ok, when I display the value of str I gotstr = 

    'GGUCUGGGGUAUUGGCAAUAUGGGGUAGAGCAAUACUCUUCCGUGUUAAGAGAAAAUAAUAUUCCAAUCG'

??? Error using ==> fprintf
Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.

Error in ==> suppI at 8
             fprintf(fid, '%s\n', str);

Comment: I'm glad to see you have resolved the problem with the help of @Pete (+1). One other suggestion: I suspect that you could definitely eliminate that double loop from your code and make it run much faster - look into functions like `ismember` and `intersect`.

Answer (score 1):

This error:

```
??? Error using ==> fprintf Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.
```

Tells you everything you need to know; str is not a character array - it's a MATLAB cell:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html

This should fix it:

```
fprintf(fid, '%s\n', str{1});
```

As a side note, that is why you should always include the error message text in the original question...

Comment: Thanks all I tried    fprintf(fid, '%s\n', cell2mat( str)); and it works well